# Compiling C with optimization flag

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization

I am comparing two assembly forms of two C files, one with an optimization flag (-O2), and the other without.

My question is:

Why is that in the optimized assembly version, the compiler puts the main function after all the helper functions, whereas the helper functions come first in the original assembly code. What does that mean in terms of efficiency? Can someone please elaborate?

Here is the original C file. Thanks!

```
// Based on a source file found in a beginner's discussion on multidimensional arrays here:
// http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/71617-3d-arrays/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int validColor( char *str );
int mathProblem( char *str );

// 1) Asks from six 'theoretical' different users one of two questions,
// allowing only three answers for each.
// 2) Stores the response into a multidimensional array

int main( void )
{
        char myArray[ 6 ][ 3 ][ 20 ]; /* Six users, three questions, and up to 19 characters per answer
(strings are '\0' terminated), though no "true" answer is that long */
        int i, valid;

/* User instructions */
        for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        {
if ( i % 2 == 0 )
{
valid = 0;
while( valid == 0 )
{
                 printf( "Enter your favorite color : " );

                 fgets( myArray[ i ][ 0 ], 20, stdin ); /* Get answer to first question */

if( myArray[ i ][ 0 ][ 0 ] == '\n' ) /* If the user just presses enter, move to next question */
break; /* Jump out of while loop */

valid = validColor( myArray [i ][ 0 ] ); /* Call function to validate answer */
}
}
if ( i % 2 == 1 )
{
valid = 0;
while( valid == 0)
                        {
                                printf( "The roots of (x - 4)^2 : " );

                                fgets(myArray[ i ][ 0 ], 20, stdin); /* Get answer to second question */

                                if(myArray[ i ][ 0 ][ 0 ] == '\n') /* If the user just presses enter, move to next question */
                                        break; /* Jump out of while loop */

                                valid = mathProblem( myArray[ i ][ 0 ] ); /* Call function to validate answer */
                        }
}
        }

        return 0;
}

int validColor( char *str )
{
if( strcmp( str, "Black\n" ) == 0 )
return 1;
if( strcmp( str, "Red\n" ) == 0 )
return 1;
if( strcmp( str, "Blue\n" ) == 0 )
return 1;

return 0; /* If no match above, answer is not valid */
}

int mathProblem( char *str )
{
if ( atoi( str ) == 2 ) /* Function call for analysis purposes */
return 1;
if ( strcmp( str, "-2\n" ) == 0 )
return 1;
if ( strcmp( str, "+2\n" ) == 0 )
return 1;

return 0; /* If no match above, answer is not valid */
}
```

Comment: In the interests of full disclosure, which compiler are you using?

Comment: What is the difference between "main function after all the helper functions" and "helper functions come first"?

Answer (score 4):

For the efficiency, John is completely right. After all is compiled in an object file, functions are just entries in a symbol table, order doesn't matter.

For your question why this order appears so:

- when not optimizing, all calls to
  functions are just references to the
  address of the function. The compiler
  can then easily emit the object code
  in the order it encounters the
  definitions of the functions.
- when optimizing, the compiler replaces
  (at least potentially) all calls to
  small functions for which it has the
  definitions at hand by inline code.
  So generally he can't emit the code
  when he encounters the function but
  has to wait until he eventually sees
  the declaration of all called
  functions. The emission order is thus
  something like an invers linear
  ordering of the call graph.

Comment: If anything, it could also be counterproductive.  The instructions are more likely to end up being broken up being in different cache lines if there's enough code prior to it.

Comment: In short it is down to the order of code generation by the compiler and nothing directly with the efficiency of the generated code.

Answer (score 3):

It will make no real difference in terms of efficiency.